# HTML5 localStorage.setItem value set but not getting value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert(localStorage.getItem(pet_name));
    $("#lost_step1").click(function(){
        alert($("#pet_name").val());
        localStorage.setItem(pet_name, $("#pet_name").val());
        alert(localStorage.getItem(pet_name));
    }
}
```

When I am reloading page than It not getting value of pet_name outside click function. It alerting inside click function. How can I resolve this error? Why it not getting value? Please help me. Rightnow I am helpless. and sorry for my weak English.

Comment: Where is `pet_name` defined/initialized? If this is coming from the element with an `id` of `pet_name`, you'll need to store that value so you can access it.

Comment: inside click function

Comment: No it's not. You have `#pet_name` as an element that you are getting the value of, but then you are writing `pet_name` as a standard JavaScript variable, which is not declared anywhere.

Comment: Here is a code line localStorage.setItem(pet_name, $("#pet_name").val());

Comment: But, `pet_name` hasn't been defined anywhere.

Comment: please give me example

Comment: `var pet_name = xyz...` If you want the value to be stored under the name "pet_name", then you need to be writing: `localStorage.setItem("pet_name", $("#pet_name").val());` with the storage item name in quotes. Without the quotes, `pet_name` is a reference to a variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: give your full code with pet_name element.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this

https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/hgf1gcz5/1/

based on your example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pet_name = "pet_name";

  alert('init --> ' + localStorage.getItem(pet_name));

  $("#lost_step1").click(function() {
    var pet_name_val = $("#pet_name").val();
    alert('before save-->' + pet_name_val);
    localStorage.setItem(pet_name, pet_name_val);
    alert('after save-->' + localStorage.getItem(pet_name));
  });
});





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="test_pet_name" id="pet_name" />
<br>
<button id="lost_step1">CLICK ME!</button>
```